# Calling Jquery function from GridView link

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview

After hours of trying every possible way, I give up. Maybe you guys can see what i'm doing wrong here.
I have a GridView with a Delete button. On the ClientClick event i call a javascript function that opens a jquery msgbox with yes/no buttons. If the user clicked yes, I would like the function `ConfirmDeleteRecord()` to return true.

This is how the "Delete" column on the GridView looks like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ClientSkuID") %>' Text="Delete" runat="server" ID="lnkDelete" OnClientClick="return ConfirmDeleteRecord()"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

This is my Javascript function:

```
function ConfirmDeleteRecord() {

var bResult = false;

$.msgBox({
    title: "Are You Sure?",
    content: "Are you sure you want to delete this record?",                    
    type: "confirm",
    buttons: [{ value: "Yes" }, { value: "No" }, { value: "Cancel"}],
    success: function (result) {
        if (result == "Yes") {
            bResult = true;
        }
    }
    });


return bResult;
```

}

The problem is that the code never get to to "return bResult" line.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work because $.msgBox is not a blocking function like confirm() is. Make sense? All that function is doing is showing some HTML. What you need to do is instead change your code from this:

```
 if (result == "Yes") {
            bResult = true;
        }
```

To something like:

```
if (result == "Yes") {
 //perform postback here to delete the record. 
}
```