# Call jQuery function from Gridview link button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

In my application I have a jQuery function, and I want to call this function from a gridview link button. I tried this code shown here, but the function is not called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(function () {
        var JavascriptBlah = '<%=msUntilFour%>'
        var fileName = '<%=msUntilFour%>';          
        $('input[id$="lnkCustomer"]').click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: fileName,
                width: 600,
                height: 600,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                open: function () {
                    var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"700px\" height=\"700px\">";
                    object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{FileName}\">here</a>";
                    object += "</object>";
                    object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "Doc/Demo.pdf");
                    $("#dialog").html(object);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Aspx markup:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" CssClass="mydatagrid" 
      HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="false"
      PageSize="10" EmptyDataText="No Records Available">
      <HeaderStyle CssClass="header"></HeaderStyle>
      <PagerStyle ForeColor="Red" HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
      <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CustomerID">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkCustomer" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'>
                  </asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
      <RowStyle CssClass="rows"></RowStyle>
   </asp:GridView>
</div>       
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
```

How can I call the jQuery function from the gridview link button?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782051/calling-jquery-function-from-gridview-link) will help you.

Comment: Thnq @devansh-nigam. It's Working

Comment: please upvote my comment if you think it is useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call function by its id as it generate multiple ids for each row.
You can achieve this by javascript simply attach a client side event onclick='myTestFun();' to LinkButton.

Answer (score 0):

First you can declare function in script section and then add in `OnClientClick` property of `LinkButton`.

**ASPX Code**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkCustomer" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'
OnClientClick="OpenModel();" > </asp:LinkButton>
```

**JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   OpenModel();
});
function OpenModel() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: fileName,
            width: 600,
            height: 600,
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            open: function () {
                var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"700px\" height=\"700px\">";
                object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{FileName}\">here</a>";
                object += "</object>";
                object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "Doc/Demo.pdf");
                $("#dialog").html(object);
            }
        });
    });
```